# Regular expressions: [a]bc vs abc

Tags: regex

I am not a regular expressions expert, but I thought I understood the basics.  I was reading a [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-determine-whether-process-is-running/) that mentioned using this syntax:

`$ ps -ewwo pid,args | grep [s]sh`

to determine if SSHD is running or not.

I do not understand why the first s is in brackets.  I would think that `ssh` and `[s]sh` would yield the same results, but I actually get different results.

```
$ ps -ewwo pid,args | grep [s]sh
 1258 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
 2988 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

$ ps -ewwo pid,args | grep ssh
 1258 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
 2988 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
 3082 grep --color=auto ssh
```

So why does it find the 3rd result in the second example?

Thanks!

Comment: In your first grep you put `ss[h]` - which does not match the rest of your comment.?

Comment: @Zac thanks, that was a typo.  Sorry, fixed.

Comment: Would this be a better fit for the [unix site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/?as=1)?

Comment: It may be, now that I understand my problem was not actually regexp comprehension.  Either way, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regular expressions `[a]bc` and `abc` match exactly the same set of strings, but they're being applied to different data, because the command-line arguments to `grep` appear in the output of the `ps` command.

Using `[a]bc` causes the literal string `"[a]bc"` to appear in the output of ps -- and this isn't matched by the regular expression `[a]bc`.

The idea is to avoid matching the line for the `grep` command itself.

Comment: you type faster than I do.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you pipe `ps` into `grep`, you'll often find the running `grep` process because the term exists in the program name and it's probable it will match.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets are a [character class](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) but it doesn't really make sense to have a character class with one character and no repeat specified.

The reason you get different results is because `ssh` matches itself the grep arguments in the process list, but it `[s]sh` does not match itself.